# Where can I find and book plane tickets on date not on destination?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, travel-agents

I have a holiday coming up and I would like to travel with the family somewhere. I have specific wishes regarding departure and arrival times, but the destination is less relevant. Where can I search on date and departure/arrival times for possible destinations?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.net)!

Enter in the 'from' part, eg, LON (London, any airport) is what I used to put when I lived there.

Delete the 'to' part, leaving it blank.

Select the dates you require, from and to.

Click search.  It will then display a list of countries by price.  Select the country of choice, and it'll show cities in that country, by price.  This is often how I'd pick my next trip to Europe - where shall I go this time....?

Comment: You stole my answer! :)

Comment: I wish I could favourite an answer sometimes rather than a question!

Comment: I find Skyscanner gives me a load of RyanAir trips to fields in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: A simple checkbox on the left once you get to your destination page lets you uncheck RyanAir. No need to look at airlines you don't want.

Answer (score 4):

Kayak Explore does just this: http://www.kayak.com/explore/

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend https://kiwi.com
it has a nice filter by radius feature.

screenshot example is for flight search from 100 km radius of Tokyo to 150 km radius around Osaka excluding Nagoya region:
[image]