# Searching for flights to destinations matching weather / flight time conditions

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, weather-and-climate

[easyJet](http://www.easyjet.com) has a neat little feature on [the route map they show on their website](http://www.easyjet.com/EN/routemap): you can set criteria such as maximum flight time and minimum temperature for the month you plan to fly from any airport, and they show you match flights.

[image]

We have had a couple of questions earlier on [searching by date](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2615/108) or ["broad" search for flights](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/730/108). Is there any online booking / search site at all similar to easyJet's site that allows search for flights using other criteria such as weather, flight times, et al?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

British Airways seems to have [a similar feature called TripSeeker](https://www.britishairways.com/travel/tripseeker/public/en_gb). You seem to get even more parameters to fiddle with!

Comment: Is the page login-only for BA Club members?

Comment: Never mind, found a public link.